Open LWC List button in same window as popup
I have a list button in OpportunityLineItemSchedule which is in related list of OpportunityLineItem. I want this button to be opened in Same window as popup. The button loads LWC component. I am unable to open this in same window as popup.
I also need to pass record id from OpportunityLineItem record page.
Or do i need to use VF page for this?

My lwc code which i am using

<template>
  <!--<template if:true={isModalOpen}>
    <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true"
      aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
      <div class="slds-modal__container">
        <header class="slds-modal__header">
          <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close"
            onclick={closeModal}>
            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" alternative-text="close" variant="inverse"
              size="small"></lightning-icon>
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
          </button>
          <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Edit Manhours</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">-->
          <lightning-card title={title}>
            <div if:true={showSpinner} class="slds-is-relative">
              <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading...">
              </lightning-spinner>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
              <template lwc:if={schedules}>
                <lightning-datatable key-field="Id" data={schedules} columns={columns} onsave={handleSave}
                  oncellchange={handleCellChange} draft-values={draftValues} hide-checkbox-column
                  onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
                </lightning-datatable>

              </template>
              <template lwc:if={error}>
                <h1> Error in lwc: {error}</h1>
              </template>
            </div><br />
            <p><b>Total Scheduled Manhours: {totalScheduledManhours}</b></p>
          </lightning-card>
        <!--</div>-->

        <!--<footer class="slds-modal__footer">
          <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={closeModal} title="Cancel">Cancel</button>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
  </template>-->
</template>

